# Azure app(mobile) service not returning class type property of class

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin, odata, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

I'm having a problem (if that can be called as a problem) with my Azure app(mobile) service. I have following EntityData object:

```
public class Role : EntityData
    {
        public string RoleCode { get; set; }

        public string RoleName { get; set; }

        public List<User> Users { get; set; }

        public new string Id { get; set; }

        public new DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public new DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

        public new byte[] Version { get; set; }
    }
```

...and class that "contains" previous (**Role** is foreign key in **User**):

```
public class User : EntityData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Surname { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    //foreign key to Role
    public Role Role { get; set; }

    public List<Appointment> appointments { get; set; }

    public new string Id { get; set; }

    public new DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    public new DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    public new byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

Tables in MSSQL DB are created well:

[image: Role table]

[image: User table]

But when I try to return all users using table controller:

```
    public IQueryable<User> GetAllUser()
    {
        return Query();
    }
```

... It returns me all users but **there is no role of that user**:

```
{
    "deleted": false,
    "version": "AAAAAAABQJY=",
    "updatedAt": "2016-09-24T14:51:06.126Z",
    "createdAt": "2016-10-11T19:43:12.165Z",
    "id": "8d5a1403-e0a1-4a69-b32d-708b3a84b260",
    "password": "passwordUsera",
    "username": "korisnik",
    "surname": "Rafailovic",
    "name": "Marija"
  }
```

All other properties are there, but not Role! I tried using Include with Query but that did not help...

Why is this happening and how can I make this to include Role in every User? I done it by using custom controller and stored procedure but that is not great solution...

Comment: can you show how did you use `Include` ?

Comment: what is this `Query()` ?

Comment: Query() - Provides a helper method for querying a backend store. For all table controllers it returns all items of desired entity (entity for which controller is focused on). I tried changing it by using: "return Query().Include(x => x.Role);" but that did not help...

Comment: can you show that helper method ? `Query()` ?

Comment: It's .NET function that returns IQueryable of some entity

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the data chapter in my book http://aka.ms/zumobook - this has specific information about relationships and what you can (and cannot) do.  Spoiler: It doesn't quite work the way you think when you push it into the offline world.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET back-end for Azure Mobile Services could easily expose your tables via Entity Framework. But, the relational queries couldn't work as expected by default.  You could try to extend your query via overriding the `DelegatingHandler` in your client side and add your custom `ActionFilterAttribute` to include the relational properties in your back-end. For more details, you could follow this official [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuremobile/2014/05/27/retrieving-data-from-1n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services/) about retrieving data with relationships via the .NET back-end for Azure Mobile Services.